# Platform support up to a certain Z height in Ultimaker Cura/G-code

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code, support-structures

Ultimaker Cura offers a platform support type of “*touching buildplate*” which enables the printer to only make a raft for parts of the object that should be touching the build plate. It also offers “*everywhere*” for any object that might be hanging over the build plate.

I have a need to only offer support for overhangs up to a certain z height, such any overhang located at a z-point of 4 mm or below. Is there a software that will enable this, either as a setting/addition to Ultimaker Cura or just a G-code export for Pronterface?

Comment: Why don't you care about overhangs higher up?  what "magic" allows those to print properly but not the lowest overhangs?  What's the real concern here?

Comment: Basically, I have an irregular structure where I need to arrange it in a certain way to limit post-print-finishing. The support structures cause some of the irregular structures to snap off when it’s removed from the print bed. I don’t think sanding or acetone baths are a good way to smooth ABS -perhaps that’s the real problem here, I need to hide support structure connections prior to post-finishing, and this irregular surface is the only spot to do that. These high-up overhangs have a very low angle of overhang and should connect fine without support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a software that will enable this?

Yes, as of Ultimaker Cura 3.3 Beta, Ultimaker Cura allows you to specify an area which will not be considered for adding supports. In your case you could define everything above 4 mm to be excluded from building support structures.

You can look [here](https://community.ultimaker.com/topic/22192-introducing-ultimaker-cura-33-beta/) for this very new feature, it might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a software that will enable this?

I don't own a copy of it, but from talking with other 3D printing enthusiasts, I know [simplify3d](https://www.simplify3d.com/) is the slicer out there with the most granular control over support structures.

I'm unaware if it has a setting for *exactly* what you want, but I know it has the possibility to manually add support in selected parts of your model, so - depending on size and complexity of your model, and on the level of accuracy you need - it may well be an option for you.

It is proprietary, commercial software with a "no question asked" refund policy.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, look into  3D modelling tools which allow you to add your own support towers to the model itself.  Do that, then set your slicing tool to "no support" or equivalent.